# The declaration position about EditText & Button

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public static final String NAME = "android.example.br.CUSTOM_INTENT";

  EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
  Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


  }
}
```

Could someone tell me why I can't new the EditText、Button out of the **onCreate** function.

```
  public static final String NAME = "android.example.br.CUSTOM_INTENT";

  EditText edt;
  Button btn;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

I know it works like this
Is it because everything(Button,editText...) will be loaded in **onCreate** function?

Sorry for my English if anything not cleared

Comment: Basically, before setting the root layout, you just can't access any view inside it and onCreate() is the very first method called when an activity is launched in which the root content view is set. After that, you can initialise any view in any method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## findViewById

As this says it will find view by some id, how can you find a view even when it is not inflated.

> Is it because everyone(Button,editText...) will be loaded in onCreate function?

**No, it is not bound to onCreate() method.** You can use `findViewById` in any method after calling `setContentView`. As below also works.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
}
```

`setContentView` creates view for your activity, once view is inflated you can find a view by its id.

> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
> EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

Again you can not use `findViewById` while initialisation because view is created after `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `findViewById()` outside the `onCreate()` method as every activity has its own lifecycle and `onCreate()` method is the first method which initializes all the objects of the view which we set in our layout file.
So, we cannot initialize them before `onCreate()` method

After that `onStart()` method is called, then `onResume()` is called where our activity is visible to the user and ready for the user's interaction.